# Flyway: Baseline won't work on existing DB

Tags: spring, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to:

1. Add my existing DB to flyway by creating a "schema-history-table".
2. Apply migration scripts to update the schema.

I'm deploying my code on a test server and I would expect maven/spring to automatically use "flyway: baseline", create the "schema-history-table" for my existing DB and apply my migration scripts afterwards.

I'm not using any java code for the migration, neither did i define anything in the pom.xml, except for the necessary imports. Since I need this thing to run on any stage without me fiddling with the DB first, I'm only using the "application.yml". Also, using the console in any way won't be possible, since I have absolutely no way of accessing the prod-stage in any other way than by code.

And yes, I've studied related posts and tried what was suggested there, I it works for my environment.

**Application.yml**

```
datasources:
  auth-db:
    url: ${secret.jdbcUrl}
    username: ${secret.username}
    password: ${secret.password}
    configuration:
      pool-name: secret-db
      read-only: false
      minimum-idle: 2
      connection-timeout: 20000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      idle-timeout: 10000
      max-lifetime: 1000
    flyway:
      enabled: true
      locations: classpath:db/migration
      baselineOnMigrate: true

#flyway:
  #url: ${secret.jdbcUrl}
  #user: ${secret.username}
  #password: ${secret.password}
  #locations: classpath:db/migration
  #baselineOnMigrate: true
```

I've tried several ways of configuring the migration, using application.yml, flyway.conf, different ways of formatting (see the commented out part) etc.
I've also tried to name the first script for the baseline "V1__Init_DB.sql" or "Baseline.sql" as suggested in several guides.

No matter what I do, it seems:

1. The DB connecting is successfully established
2. It finds my migration scripts
3. It refuses to execute "baselineOnMigrate", even though it's specified in the application.yml

See the (formatted) logs below. It ignores 2 migration scripts and accepts 1. This had to be expected since I intentionally disabled one of them and the other one is called "Baseline.sql", which doesn't follow the convention (guess calling it "Baseline.sql" is just nonsense). But that's not the issue here, since I've tried to name "Baseline.sql", "V1__Init_DB.sql" as stated before and the result is the same.

Any Ideas, why it won't do the (baseline) migration?

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:10.266Z","@version":"1","message":"Flyway Community Edition 9.5.0 by Redgate","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:10.267Z","@version":"1","message":"","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}

{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:10.352Z","@version":"1",**"message":"2 SQL migrations were detected but not run because they did not follow the filename **convention.","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.resource.ResourceNameValidator","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:10.352Z","@version":"1","message":"If this is in error, enable debug logging or 'validateMigrationNaming' to fail fast and see a list of the invalid file names.","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.resource.ResourceNameValidator","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:12.111Z","@version":"1","message":"Database: ***** (Oracle 19.1)","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.BaseDatabaseType","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}

{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:12.597Z","@version":"1","**message":"Successfully validated 1 migration** (execution time 00:00.041s)","logger_name":"org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.042Z","@version":"1","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticatorRepository' defined in file [/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes/de/secret/test/authorizer/AuthenticatorRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) \"MY_DB\" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table. ","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","thread_name":"main","level":"WARN","level_value":30000}**

{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.044Z","@version":"1","message":"secret-db - Shutdown initiated...","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.055Z","@version":"1","message":"secret-db - Shutdown completed.","logger_name":"com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.147Z","@version":"1","message":"Stopping service [Tomcat]","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.174Z","@version":"1","message":"\n\nError starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-08-07T09:06:13.248Z","@version":"1","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticatorRepository' defined in file [/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes/de/secret/test/authorizer/AuthenticatorRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) \"MY_DB\" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.\n\tat
```

Comment: Looks like I've found the solution myself. The following is the correct configuration that worked for me:  ``` spring:
    flyway:
      enabled: true
      locations: classpath:db/migration
      baselineOnMigrate: true
      validateOnMigrate: false
      table: SCHEMA_HISTORY_TABLE ``` Sorry, formatting doesn't seem to be an option for answers...